# Differences between u[x,y,t] vs. u[x,y][t] vs. u[x][y][t]

Tags: functions, function-construction

Is there any difference between defining a variable by `u[x,y,t]` or `u[x,y][t]` or `u[x][y][t]` ?

I understand that beeing used in `NDSolve` the appropriate way to define it is either `u[x,y][t]` or `u[x][y][t]` in order to declare the dependent variable as `u[x,y]` or `u[x][y]` and the derivative vs time with prime notation as `u[x,y]'[t]` or `u[x][y]'[t]`.

For the first notation the derivative would be `D[u[x,y,t],t]` and the dependent variable u ?

I would appreciate if anybody could comment on which is the reason to select any of the three forms ?

Comment: For `NDSolve`, I've only ever used or seen `u[x,y,t]`.